# How do I import a module from a different `/node_modules/` folder

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules, es6-modules

This is my files structure:

```
├── public/
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   │   ├── jquery
│   │   │   ├── etc... 
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├──  icons
│   │   ├──  package.json
│   ├── es
│   │   ├── index.js
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   ├── scss
│   ├── css
│   ├── index.php
├── app/
│   ├── contollers
│   ├── models
│   ├── views
│   ├── helpers
├── node_modules/
│   ├── webpack/
│   │   ├── ... 
│   │   │   ├── ...
├── package.json
└── webpack.conf.js/
```

I created 2 separate npms, one for the root folder (`/www`) for development, and an other for the assets (images, icons and node_modules) under `public/assets/`.

I want to load the jquery library (for example) module to my `index.js` file.

Tried:

```
import '../scss/style.scss';

import {$,jQuery} from '../assets/node_models/jquery';
```

returns

> ERROR in ./public/es/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../assets/node_models/jquery' in '/www/public/es'  @
>   ./public/es/index.js 5:14-53

This  is my webpack.conf.js file:

```
const path              = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UrlLoader         = require('url-loader');

module.exports = {

    entry: { 
                main: './public/es/index.js' 
    },
    output: {
                path:       path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/'),
                filename:   'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
                rules: [
                            {
                                test:       /\.js$/,
                                exclude:    /node_modules/,
                                use: {
                                        loader: "babel-loader"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                test: /\.s?css$/,
                                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                                })
                            }, 
                            {
                                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                                use: [{
                                    loader: 'url-loader',
                                    options: {
                                      limit: 100000
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                ]
    },
    plugins: [
                new ExtractTextPlugin({
                    filename: '../css/main-style.css' 
                }), 
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    inject: false,
                    hash: true,
                    template: './public/index.php',
                    filename: 'index.php'
                })
    ],
    devServer: {
                    port:           3000,
                    contentBase:    __dirname + '/public/js', 
                    inline:         true
    }

};
```

How can I load modules from an other folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import jquery like this:
`import $ from 'assets/node_modules/jquery';`

Also you can improve you webpack a little bit:

```
const path              = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UrlLoader         = require('url-loader');


publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
appFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');

module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        modules: [ publicFolder, appFolder ],
        extensions: [ '.js', ],
    },

    entry: { 
                main: './public/es/index.js' 
    },
    output: {
                path:       path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/'),
                filename:   'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
                rules: [
                            {
                                test:       /\.js$/,
                                exclude:    /node_modules/,
                                use: {
                                        loader: "babel-loader"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                test: /\.s?css$/,
                                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                                })
                            }, 
                            {
                                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                                use: [{
                                    loader: 'url-loader',
                                    options: {
                                      limit: 100000
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                ]
    },
    plugins: [
                new ExtractTextPlugin({
                    filename: '../css/main-style.css' 
                }), 
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    inject: false,
                    hash: true,
                    template: './public/index.php',
                    filename: 'index.php'
                })
    ],
    devServer: {
                    port:           3000,
                    contentBase:    __dirname + '/public/js', 
                    inline:         true
    }

};
```

I have added

```
publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
appFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
```

and

```
resolve: {
    modules: [ publicFolder, appFolder ],
    extensions: [ '.js', ],
},
```

after that you can import any thing from `publicFolder`, `appFolder` as from node_modules. e.g.

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'assets/node_models/jquery';
```

Comment: I added the 2 new variables. added resolve withe the settings you mentioned and changed my import statment: 
`ERROR in ./public/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/node_models/jquery' in '/www/public/es'
 @ ./public/es/index.js 5:14-50

Comment: webpack configuration is ok. problem is `jquery` don't provide `$` `jquery` for you so you can't import them. Install loadash and try `import _ from 'assets/node_modules/lodash';` you will see it works as expected.

Comment: I tried installing jquery under `/www` just for the sports, and it did work using `$` and `jquery`... but did try to test it with you're exmaple: 

ERROR in ./public/es/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/node_modules/lodash' in '/www/public/es'
 @ ./public/es/index.js 5:14-51

Comment: I console.loged the paths, are these the right values? `/www/public`
`/www/app`

Comment: Hmm, yes `/www/public` and `/www/app` should be right. Ok, wait a little bit. I will try to recreate all you project structure.

Comment: Spasiba very much :D

Comment: Here we go! :)
https://github.com/Arseniy-II/test
`npm install` + `cd public/assets && npm install` + `cd ../../` + `npm run build`
you will have index.html open it and check the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179540/discussion-between-arseniy-ii-and-rick-sanchez).

Comment: Works from your repo.. but why

Comment: It happens from time to time. Usually I solve such problems by gadually moving from working example to my own project.

Comment: IDK what the h happened, I installed lodash to my assets directory, and it worked. So i figured it's the jquery library that was the problem. but it did work from the main directory (`www`) and i cannot understand why. For now i used `import * as $ from 'assets/node_modules/jquery';`, how do i get to know what does jquery exports?

Comment: package.json directs here `"main": "dist/jquery.js",`. I have looked through. And it looks like it gives you only `return jQuery;` but it may be trickier then that.